# Why does Xamarin Forms Maps crash in UWP App?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms

I'm having a hard time trying to show a map on my Xamarin Forms UWP app. This is the error I get every time I open the page with the map:

[image]

The exception:

```
Exception   {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005):
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.}
System.Exception {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException}
```

Error code:
-2147467259

Message: `"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."  string`

[image]

In the file MainPage.cs the project UWP I have the next code:

In the MainPage.cs file of the UWP project I have the following code:

```
Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init ("API KEY");
LoadApplication(new Shopm.App());
```

The API key is Bing Maps. The API key that I created is with Type of key: Basic / Other public mobile application. It is right?

Only three options appear for creating an API KEY.

[image]

I followed the steps of the Xamarin.Forms page.

In Android its works but in UWP when clicking on a button for maps breaks my app.

Comment: *Application type*: Select *Universal Windows App* for use in your Universal Windows app.. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/authentication-key

Comment: Create a New Key following the steps on the documentation https://stackoverflow.com/a/51002263/194717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For UWP the correct selection is that:

*Application type*: Select *Universal Windows App* for use in your Universal Windows app..

This is an example of what the form looks like.
[image: Bing Maps key]

Follow the steps on this Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/authentication-key

Comment: I only appear three options: Other public mobile app, public website, dev/test

Comment: Did you start from URL https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ I tested here it goes to https://www.bingmapsportal.com/Application# and there are options, among this *Basic / Public Windows App (UWP, 8.x, and earlier)*

Comment: I tested it right now, tell me if create a new key shows that other options If not, tell me here in comments and I will remove my answer, so someone else can figure it out. OK?

Comment: Ok, the problem was that. The day that the KEY API was created, that option did not appear and now it does. Bug the Microsoft.

Comment: Maybe something caused by their moving and consolidating the Bing / Azure services and also the UWP framework updates and new features.